# How do I call a remote API when creating a Chrome Extension (Utilizing the JQuery Library)?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Is this possible?

I like JQuery much better than raw Javascript. Can the JQuery library functions such as Load be used for a remote domain if you have set the permissions appropriately in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can either include the url to the script you want to work with or keep the script local to the extension folder and just use it's name in the manifest.

The remote domain is neither here nor there though. Your manifest indicates what url's are going to be exposed to the extension by some combination of exact URL or URL and wildcards or all URLs by using just wildcards.